# How do you check a mock was called with a Seq irrespective of order

Tags: scala, scalatest, mockito-scala

I have a method, which has been mocked, and takes a Seq as a parameter.

I want to check the method was called with a Seq with the same contents, but irrespective of order.

eg something like:

```
myMethod(Seq(0,1)) wasCalled once
```

which passes if we called `myMethod(Seq(1,0))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider [`argThat`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala/blob/dd356ce5d329b65ec4ae7d6bae66df4ccbf3dc43/common/src/main/scala/org/mockito/matchers/ThatMatchers.scala#L18) matcher which enables specifying a predicate matcher

```
argThat((s: Seq[Int]) => s.sorted == Seq(0,1))
```

For example

```
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}
import org.mockito.{ArgumentMatchersSugar, IdiomaticMockito}

trait Qux {
  def foo(s: Seq[Int]): Int
}

class ArgThatSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with IdiomaticMockito with ArgumentMatchersSugar {
  "ArgThat" should "match on a predicate" in {
    val qux = mock[Qux]
    qux.foo(argThat((s: Seq[Int]) => s.sorted == Seq(0,1))) answers (42)
    qux.foo((Seq(1,0))) shouldBe (42)
  }
}
```